# Is there any way to use user's input in batch file to use it in command?

Tags: batch-file

is there any way that batch file in windows can save and use user's input in command like:

"

```
What's your name? Joe
Hello Joe!
```

"

thanks!

Comment: Please read my answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) There is everything explained in full details with examples you need to know on prompting a user for a string during execution of a batch file and use the input string in a safe and secure manner.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo What's your name?
set /p name=
echo Hallo %name%!
```

Comment: Why the initial `echo`, when you can include it in the prompt string itself? 1. `:GetName`, 2. `@Set "name="`, 3. `@Set /P "name=What is your name?>"`, 4. `@If Not Defined name GoTo GetName`, 5. `@Echo Hello %name%`, 6. `@Pause`.

Comment: See what happens with your code if the user enters `& call dir "%UserProfile%\Desktop" /B /S & rem ` with a space at end. This code is not secure. It works on user inputs something expected by the author of the batch file. But I know people who enter a string containing `&` or other characters with special meaning for command processor on asking for a name because they want to be funny and enter a string being an emoji. The last command line should be at least `if defined name setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo Hello !name!^^!& endlocal`.

Comment: …or `:LOOP`, then `set /P name="What's your name? " || goto :LOOP`, then `echo Hello %name%!`…